# How to fix position of content below content changing height

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, height, jquery-isotope

I have content in my web page which changes height dynamically (jquery isotope plugin). I don't want the content below the dynamic content to jump up and down but to stay still.

I think, what I need to is the follwing: for every pixel the dynamic content grows the content below should be moved up by scrolling down in the page for a pixel. for every pixel the dynamic content shrinks I have to scroll up the page.

Is this possible in a way that the content below stands absolutely still?

Thanks,
Roland

Answer (score 1):

why don't you wrap the dynamic content inside a div, then give that div a fixed height, this way the content, will only change its height within the div, and the content below, will stay still.

this is an example

```
<style>
    .wrapper {
        width: 200px;
        height: 500px;
    }

    .wrapper .dynamic {
        background-color: crimson;
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
    }
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="dynamic"></div>
</div>
<p>
    am the content, that should stay still.
</p>

<script>
    var dynamic = document.getElementsByClassName('dynamic')[0];

    dynamic.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
        dynamic.style.height = 500;
    });

    dynamic.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
        dynamic.style.height = 200;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but then the dynamic content will either get a scrollbar or have unused space at the end. Also I don't want to use position: fixed for the lower content.

Comment: for the scroll bar, you can just adjust the height of the wrapper, but for the unused space, i don't now how you intend to fill it when without moving the content below up, i think i miss understand what you need, can you clarify your needs?